# linux automatic change permissions in resolv.file

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, auditd

In various linux servers I see how the permissions of the /etc/resolv.conf file change automatically.

In state normal:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 103 Jul  4 11:50 resolv.conf
```

In changed state:

```
-r--r----- 1 root root 103 Jul  4 11:50 resolv.conf
```

I installed auditd for monitoring it, and these are the two entries between the change:

```
type=PATH msg=audit(07/04/2012 12:20:02.719:303) : item=0 name=/etc/resolv.conf inode=137102 dev=fe:00 mode=file,644 ouid=root ogid=root rdev=00:00 
type=CWD msg=audit(07/04/2012 12:20:02.719:303) :  cwd=/ 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(07/04/2012 12:20:02.719:303) : arch=x86_64 syscall=open success=yes exit=3 a0=7feeb1405dec a1=0 a2=1b6 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1585 pid=3445 auid=unset uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=hostid exe=/usr/bin/hostid key=(null) 

type=PATH msg=audit(07/04/2012 12:50:03.727:304) : item=0 name=/etc/resolv.conf inode=137102 dev=fe:00 mode=file,440 ouid=root ogid=root rdev=00:00 
type=CWD msg=audit(07/04/2012 12:50:03.727:304) :  cwd=/ 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(07/04/2012 12:50:03.727:304) : arch=x86_64 syscall=open success=yes exit=3 a0=7f2bcf7abdec a1=0 a2=1b6 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1585 pid=3610 auid=unset uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=hostid exe=/usr/bin/hostid key=(null)
```

any ideas about the change of permissions?

**FIXED:**
puppet was configured and running on the server, it changed the file.

Comment: Any ideas about *what*?

Comment: Are you using dhcp to get your network configuration?

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong between your `auditd` log and the timing of your two `ls` commands.

The first line says `mode=file,644` but the first `ls` shows the file has mode 444.  The second line is consistent; `mode=file,440` and the `ls` shows the file with mode 440.

You might want to run your experiment again, possibly automating the `ls` captures with something like this:

```
while true; do echo -n `date`" "; ls -l /etc/resolv.conf; sleep 5; done > ~/resolv-ls.log
```

Also check to see if there are any other entries in your auditd.log regarding `resolv.conf`.

---

It's probably also worth asking a specific question in your question, such as "What process is doing this?" or "Why does the process do this?" or "What is the appropriate ownership and mode for `/etc/resolv.conf`?"